# Geting acces to method from class in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

how can i get access to method in class from arraylist?

```
ArrayList car = new ArrayList<>;
car.add(new carClass("Audi", 35000));
System.out.println("The price is:"+ car.get(0) );
```

i woud like to get only price from this arraylist (method getPrice)

Comment: `car.get(0).getPrice()` --- Two remarks: classes in Java should always start wiht an uppercase letter (`carClass` -> `CarClass`, or just `Car`) --- Since `car` is a `List`, I would recommend calling the variable `cars`.

Comment: Instead of `carClass`, just use `Car` (capital mean class). And maybe call `car`, `cars` since it's holding multiple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, replace

```
ArrayList car = new ArrayList<>;
```

with

```
List<Car> carList = new ArrayList<>();
```

and then do as follows:

```
System.out.println("The price is:"+ carList.get(0).getPrice());
```

Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html) for more understanding on this topic.

Finally, you should follow the [Java naming convention](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) e.g. `carClass` should be `CarClass` or simply, `Car`.